# How to compile and run the virtio_test under linux/tools/virtio/virtio_test

Tags: linux-kernel

How to compile and run the virtio_test under linux/tools/virtio/virtio_test? Can someone share the exact compile and execution commands? To be more specific,
1. How to compile the virtio_test?
2. How to run it, in host or guest machine?
3. Does any specific device need to be created for the test?

I tried $make -C tools/virtio, get error
ERROR: modpost: "vhost_dev_init" [~/linux/tools/virtio/vhost_test/vhost_test.ko] undefined!

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to have `vhost` module also compiled, try to compile kernel first (`make moduels && make`) and to compile

2) Everything run in host (in fact, there is no guest at all in the tests, think the tests as "qemu" userland program).

3) No specific device needs to be created by you, just load the vhost module prior to run the tests.